# Finding word with centain length containing characters from interval

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to print all words that are 3 chararcers long and those characters are from [a-s] interval. I have tried following

```
grep '\<[a-s]\{3\}\>' file.txt
```

which outputs nothing , i have also tried

```
grep '^[a-s]\{3\}$' file.txt
```

which also did nothing even when file containes just one word. (for ^ as start and $ as end of the line)
How could i input words 3 char long from char interval / and how could i print words 3char long without interval?

Comment: That's the way to do it.  If you want to print only the matching words, one per line, use `grep -o`.  The best way to test it is to enter the command without a filename and type lines in directly.  If you're examples don't work, then I would think that either, you didn't actually execute those commands or the patterns are not in file.txt, or something else is wrong with file.txt such as encoding.

Comment: Have you `alias grep`?

Comment: You can check that it's not grep playing up by using sed: `printf "%s\n" a bad boy rand over the bad boy ran | sed -n '/\<[a-s]\{3\}\>/p'`